# How to avoid code duplication defining similar classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have one superclass:

```
(header.h)
class Super
{
    virtual void method1 () = 0;
    virtual void method2 () = 0;
    virtual void method3 () = 0;
}
```

This class is inherited by many subclasses. All these subclasses implement three methods, and they all have the same signature, like:

```
(header.h)
class A : public Super
{
    void method1 ();
    void method2 ();
    void method3 ();
}

class B : public Super
{
    void method1 ();
    void method2 ();
    void method3 ();
}

class C : public Super
{
    void method1 ();
    void method2 ();
    void method3 ();
}
```

The difference is only in the implementation of these methods, that is defined in specific .cpp file for each subclass. In the real case, I have about 20 similar subclasses, so if I need to change arguments of some method, I'd have to change it in all 20 classes, which is not not good.
So the question is, how can I avoid code duplication in this case?

Comment: If the methods do different things it's not really code duplication.

Comment: You could write a code generator, it should be easy to generate class definitions, function definitions could be more hassle.

Comment: If you need to change arguments of 20 functions, then you need to change 20 functions. There isn't a way to avoid that other than choose the arguments correctly in the first place.

Comment: Use an IDE with code refactoring features. Visual Studio 2019 can refactor a virtual method signature automatically in the entire hierarchy.

Comment: Where does the argument come from? Is it something that could be a member variable for a derived class?

Comment: This is the reason why abstract classes exist in OOP - interface is shared, but implementations are different, just as you described it. If you feel that the implementation is **similar**, maybe something could be generalized. But you'd have to share some implementations...